# Ubuntu gnome 16.04 unable to start X

Tags: 16.04, xorg

I have upgraded Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 to 16.04. After that I am unable to boot it neither in systemd mode nor in upstart mode. I want to ask about booting ubuntu in upstart mode: Boot menu -> Advanced mode -> Ubuntu 16.04 (Upstart).
During the loading it falls in command line mode with the following message:

```
upstart: systemd-logind[2587]: Failed to start user service, ignoring: Unknown unit: user@1000.service
```

How to fix that ?